# Select non-duplicate data from Table1 and insert into Table2

Tags: sql

I have a table we'll call Table1 with a bunch of junk data in it and no unique identifier column.

I want to select some columns from Table1 and transfer the data to Table2. However, I want to prevent duplicate entries from 3 of the columns from being inserted.

Let's say I have a row with desired columns `[FirstName]`, `[LastName]`, `[CompanyName]`, `[City]`, and `[State]` to be transferred. I want only the rows with unique combinations of `[FirstName]`, `[LastName]`, and `[CompanyName]` to be copied to Table2 along with their respective `[City]` and `[State]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have data like the following which you want to scrub:

```
FirstName  | LastName  | CompanyName  | City       | State
----------------------------------------------------------
Bob        |  Smith    |  ABC         | New York   |  NY
Bob        |  Smith    |  ABC         | Newark     |  NJ
Jane       |  Adams    |  ACME        | Seattle    |  WA
```

Therefore I am assuming you mean "their respective city and state" to mean "one randomly-selected city and state from the corresponding rows", which is what actually makes the problem difficult:

```
WITH [Names] AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [FirstName], [LastName], [CompanyName]
    FROM Table1
)
INSERT INTO Table2 ([FirstName], [LastName], [CompanyName], [City], [State])
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [CompanyName], [City], [State]
FROM [Names]
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [City], [State]
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.[FirstName] = [Names].[FirstName]
    AND Table1.[LastName] = [Names].[LastName]
    AND Table1.[CompanyName] = [Names].[CompanyName]
) [FirstRespectiveAddress]
```

If "some random row" does not work for you, you will have to explicitly define which city and state to take for each person.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies everyone. Well, I do need to maintain the integrity of the row, so a random city/state will not work. Since there is years of data in the table, I cannot explicitly fill in city/state row by row either. Would copying over the entire row then deleting duplicates based on [FirstName], [LastName], and [CompanyName] be a better option? And how would I go about doing that? Table2 has foreign key dependencies if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user1994209 Which ever way you do it, by a select or a copy/delete, you have to decide which rows are valid to delete. In the example in this answer, what would be the desired end result in Table2 and why?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any preferences on which City/State are selected for each `FirstName / LastName / CompanyName` combination, you can just use a `LEFT JOIN` to do it fairly simply and without depending on any particular SQL dialect;

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT DISTINCT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.CompanyName, t1.City, t1.State
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 d
ON t1.FirstName = d.FirstName AND t1.LastName  = d.LastName AND
   t1.CompanyName = d.CompanyName AND (t1.City > d.City OR t1.State > d.State)
WHERE d.FirstName IS NULL;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/196d1/3).

The query will basically take all rows (per FirstName/LastName/CompanyName combination) that don't have a greater (by sort order) City/State combination and show them.

Answer (score 0):

You can  make a loop, Starting transfer each row and before every insert query put if condition That check the number of rows of another query that's check if values of the Col you are inserting is exist.
For example, select Col,Col,Col from table where Col=value that you want to insert,it's applicable for how much cols you need. Than make mysql_num_rows,  if the var is bigger than zero,  it's already  in the table and you don't insert it.
Hope you understood.

Comment: While this will accomplish what you want, it is a O(n^2) RBAR algorithm which will be slower than slow.

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you only the rows with unique combinations of [FirstName], [LastName], and [CompanyName]:

```
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.CompanyName, t1.City, t1.State
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT FirstName, LastName, CompanyName
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, CompanyName
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t2 ON t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName AND t1.CompanyName = t2.CompanyName
```